# Installing memcached for a django project

Tags: django, linux, caching, memcached

From the django docs:

> After installing Memcached itself, you'll need to install a memcached binding. There are several python memcached bindings available; the two most common are python-memcached and pylibmc.

The pylibmc docs have their own requirements:

```
-libmemcached 0.32 or later (last test with 0.51)
-zlib (required for compression support)
-libsasl2 (required for authentication support)
```

So it seems to me that I need to do the following:

```
-install memcached
-install libmemcached
-install zlib
-install libsas12
-install pylibmc
```

How/where can I do this? I've been used to just pip installing whatever I need but I can't even tell which of these are python packages. Are these bundled together anywhere?

Comment: What OS you're trying to install this on plays a big part in giving you an answer.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Just do `pip install python-memcached` and you should be good.

As for installing memcached itself, it depends on the platform you are on.

- Windows - http://pureform.wordpress.com/2008/01/10/installing-memcache-on-windows-for-php/
- OS X - `brew install memcached`
- Debian/Ubuntu - `sudo apt-get install memcached`

On OS X/Linux, just run `memcached` in the command line.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I'm trying to get my sudo password on my server. This seems pretty straightforward but I'll let you know once I give it a go!

Comment: Go ahead and add `sudo apt-get install libmemcached-tools` so you can use **memcstat** to tell the status of your memcached. i.e. `$ watch -n1 -d 'memcstat --servers localhost`

Answer (score 23):

Detailed explanation here http://ilian.i-n-i.org/caching-websites-with-django-and-memcached/

The link above includes explanations for how to install Memcached on Ubuntu, how to configure it as cache engine in your Django project and how to use it.