# How does caching affect memory consumption?

Tags: django, caching

I have an app which has a search feature. This feature looks up the search term in a giant object (dictionary) that I cache for 24 hours. The object is about 50,000 keys and weighs roughly 10MB.

When I profile the memory usage on my hosting, I notice that after a few queries, the memory usage goes from around 50MB to over 450MB, prompting my hosting provider to kill the app.

So I'm wondering what is going on here. Specifically, how does the cache utilize the memory on each request and what can I do to fix this?

Comment: What caching technology are you using? Memcached?

Comment: At the moment, I'm using `FileBasedCache`

Comment: File cache won't cause memory leak. Does your project have other places where you store querysets or objects in local memory? I.e as [contenttype manager does](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#the-contenttypemanager)

Comment: Not that I know of. Once I grab the IDs that I need from the cached object, I perform a query and pass along the results to the template. That's it.

Comment: Then it might be the query itself. Log the searching items that dramatically increase the memory footprint and profile its query.

Comment: Dumb question: don't you have DEBUG enabled? It saves full query log in memory. Also, are you absolutely sure your mega-object is being taken from cache all the time and is being deleted (maybe manually, with `del obj`) right after using?

Comment: @ilvar DEBUG is set to False. I am absolutely sure the object is being taken from cache but I am definitely not using `del`. I've never heard of Python requiring cleanup before so this is new.

Comment: @okm To clarify, when I mentioned "queries" I was referring to the actual search that is performed against the cached object using the `get` method. I wasn't speaking of any ORM queries.

Comment: Python has a good garbage collector inside that's why you haven't heard of it :) But sometimes it's useful to delete objects manually, and even call the collector in rare cases.

Comment: Also, do you store whole object in one cache key and retrieve it completely on every call? Maybe there's a way to retrieve only necessary data, or some part of data?

Comment: @ilvar I placed `del` statements in several places - same results unfortunately. After having spent all day yesterday on this, it seems the size of the object is the main driver here. If I cut down on the size to, say 20,000 objects, the memory consumption decreases substantially.

Comment: Then I recommend to split data somehow. Maybe you can pre-filter data using a separate list of dict keys? So you can put all key-values into separate cache keys, and retrieve only part of them which has passed that filter.

Comment: Please update your question with more specifics.  It is not clear you're using Django or Python until reading these comments.  It's also not clear whether you're talking about a Django specific or Python specific "caching" problem.   You say you have a "giant object", what *is* that?  A dict in python?  An "object" from django?  That you have "50,000 keys" isn't all that helpful, the kind of data you have (each "object") and what you're putting it *in* (dict? what?) is.

Answer (score 1):

Django FileBasedCache is known for having performance issues. You can get a big picture on the following links:

[A smarter filebasedcache for Django](http://fzysqr.com/2012/04/07/a-smarter-filebasedcache-for-django/)

[Bug: File based cache not very efficient with large amounts of cached files](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11260)

Bug was set as *wont fix* arguing:

> *I'm going to wontfix, on the grounds that the filesystem cache is intended as an easy way to test caching, not as a serious caching
>   strategy. The default cache size and the cull strategy implemented by
>   the file cache should make that obvious.*

Comment: I don't cache a bunch of objects as mentioned in your examples. I have one with a bunch of keys. I don't think your example applies. Also, the memory usage goes up after each query - it plateaus at some point, but then my hosting provider kills the app.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a KVS like Memcache or Redis as a caching strategy because they both support expiry.  Also, consider a dedicated search like ElasticSearch if more anticipated features will be search-related.

Tools are howtos are available:

[Installing memcached for a django project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636108/installing-memcached-for-a-django-project)

http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewStart

http://redis.io/commands/expire

https://github.com/bartTC/django-memcache-status

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/cache.html